# Javascript .files[0] can use in ie8 ,9 ,10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

Javascript `.files[0]` can use in `ie8` ,`9` ,`10` ?

I tested my code (javascript get file size before upload) on modern browser. it's work good.

and not work on my `ie7`.

I want to know `.files[0]` are work in `ie8` , `9` , `10` or not ?

If possible, could you please give me some browser and version that support Javascript `.files[0]`

https://jsfiddle.net/gg1j970x/

```
<script>
function test_fn() {
    var xx_data = document.getElementById("xx");
    var xx_data_file = xx_data.files[0];
    var xx_data_file_size = xx_data_file.size;  
    alert("file size : " +xx_data_file_size+" kB");
};
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). The File API page says IE 10 and up, so I would assume that goes for FileList as well.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says IE10 supporting `files` property. Make sure you run your page in HTML5 mode, not in HTML4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interesting question, answer here - > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size

also you need to change it to "bytes" `alert("file size : " +xx_data_file_size+" bytes");`